# For loop in R error message: Error in qr.default(t(const)) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, syntax-error, spline

Please help me fix this for loop.

To download the data type the following commands, noting that "username" and "password" needs to be replaced by your logging information from the Human Mortality Database. You can go to website https://mortality.org/ and create the account (will take less than 30s).

```
library(demography)
JPNmort <- hmd.mx(country = "JPN", username = "username", password = "password")
```

```
library(demography)
library(splines)

#Read Japan mortality data from the Human Mortality Database
JPNmort <- hmd.mx("JPN","username","password")

age = 2:110

data1= cbind(1:109, 
                 JPNmort[["rate"]][["total"]][age, "2016"], 
                 JPNmort[["pop"]][["total"]][age, "2016"])
data2 = cbind(1:109, 
                   JPNmort[["rate"]][["total"]][age, "2017"],
                   JPNmort[["pop"]][["total"]][age, "2017"])



#Reformat data rows and columns
column.names = c("Age", "mu_x", "Ec_x")
rownames(data1) = NULL
rownames(data2) = NULL

colnames(data1) = column.names
colnames(data2) = column.names

the.knots <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
hyper_param <- expand.grid(
  unlist(lapply(seq_along(the.knots), combn, x = the.knots, simplify = FALSE), recursive = FALSE),
  c(0)
)

colnames(hyper_param) <- c("knots", "Error.Rate")

# Initialize lists to store the results
my.basis <- vector("list", nrow(hyper_param))
my.spline <- vector("list", nrow(hyper_param))


for (i in 1:nrow(hyper_param)) {
  

  my.knots <- as.numeric(unlist(hyper_param[i, 1]))
  

  my.basis[[i]] <- ns(data1[, "Age"], 
                      knots = setdiff(my.knots, c(my.knots[1], my.knots[length(my.knots)])), 
                      Boundary.knots = c(my.knots[1], my.knots[length(my.knots)])
  )
  my.spline[[i]] <- lm(data1[, "mu_x"] ~ my.basis[[i]], weights = data1[, "Ec_x"] / data1[, "mu_x"])
  
 
  hyper_param$Error.Rate[i] <- mean((data2[, "mu_x"] - fitted(my.spline[[i]]))^2)
}
```

The codes run perfectly when I fix `i` with a specific value but when I run the for-loop it returns the error message as:

```
Error in qr.default(t(const)) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Comment: have you attempted to run `debug()` on it/are you familiar with how `debug()` works in R?

Comment: @Mark: clearly OP has not!  OP: please make your code reproducible - `the.knots` vs `theknots` and identify the source of `ns`.  is it `shiny`, `splines` or somewhere else?  The community is happy to help you but expects you to have made sufficient effort to allow us to do so.

Comment: @Limey idk mate, I prefer not to assume. Clearly it's unlikely but not impossible. Part of bringing it up is, if OP hasn't heard of it, they can then learn about it

Comment: Thanks @Mark and Limey ! My apologies, I have just edited the codes so it can be reproducible.

Comment: Thanks Mark and @Limey ! My apologies, I have just edited the codes so it can be reproducible. –

Comment: JaFranke you didn't answer my question! :-o

Comment: Sorry @Mark ! I have no clues about how `debug()` works in R. How would you suggest I apply it in this case?

Comment: it depends what program you are coding within, but in general the way I often debug things is by putting it all within a function `foo()`, then load the function into the environment, run `debug(foo)`, then run `foo()`. You should be able then to step through the code as it is running, seeing what each of the variables are

Comment: this is useful in three main ways: 1., it means you can see where in a loop it is breaking, and 2., you are able to see what variables are equal to at different points (which may or may not be what you expect), and 3. it enables you at any point (e.g. the point at which it breaks) to try running different code and see if that works instead. In essence, it turns a big piece of code into something you can play with interactively

Comment: Elisa's answer is great, but despite its quality, it's a give a man a fish-type answer, if you get what I mean. I find that most answers here are those types of answers. But Stack Overflow isn't great at teaching people how to fish. If you get comfortable with debugging, it will dramatically cut down the number of times you get stumped writing code (not just with R!) and need to come back here with more questions :')

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark ! So much I've learned from your comment. I will dig into the method that you suggested. Really appreciate your help!! :') <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is given by:

```
my.basis[[i]] <- ns(data1[, "Age"], 
                      knots = setdiff(my.knots, c(my.knots[1], my.knots[length(my.knots)])), 
                      Boundary.knots = c(my.knots[1], my.knots[length(my.knots)])
  )
```

Specifically, the first 9 elements of `hyper_param` are not vectors with more than one element, so the function `setdiff()` gives a numeric(0) as result.
To solve the problem you can start your for loop at 10 or add an if() where you discriminate the knots by lengths.

Comment: Absolute genius! Thank you so much @Elisa Thouverai . Your answer has completely solved the problem.